# Including Offline video in html?

Tags: jquery, html, video-streaming

I am embedding the video in my html say from variuos resources like youtube, amazon s3 server etc

Here is the example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Here is my first embedded video 
<object data="linke to youtube video" width="560" height="315"></object>-->

</body>
</html>
```

I need to have offline video feature also (like youtube) where user can watch video even if he is offline. Is there any HTML 5 feature/third party plugin like
from jquery etc which can do this trick ?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

Comment: @guest271314  Get Resource are anyways cached by default. Also videos i am embedding are from amazon cloud or youtube store so I don't have control to manifest file there as suggested

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you can use **http://www.youtubeinmp4.com/** to download the videos as MP4. Second of all, place this in your document.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="YOUR_VIDEO_HERE.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

You can change the width and height if you wish, and you will have to put the video in the same folder as your video. Also, change `YOUR_VIDEO_HERE.mp4` to your filename.
[More about the video tag at w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)